# Using underscore/lodash as template engine in Sails JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, sails.js, lodash

I have a single page web app which uses backbone in the client, and node (Sails) on the server.

I currently use lodash.underscore as the template engine in the client, and kiwi on the server.

I wish to implement pushstate with progressive enhancement. i.e. the client and server will share the same template files.

This means they'll need to use the same template engine; I have decided to go with underscore/lodash.

Within Sails config\views.js it implies you can use underscore as the template engine. Problem is I cant work out how to do this. I've included it in my package.json and set

```
'engine': 'underscore'
```

I then get an error when firing up my app - "callback function required at Function.app.engine"

If I set the engine to 'kiwi', 'jade', 'ejs' etc then it'll work.

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what your asking, however, I've used underscore templates in my server-side views with the following configuration:

In `config/views` I set my engine to ejs:

```
engine: 'ejs',
```

And in my `Gruntfile.js` I've set:

```
var templateFilesToInject = [
    'linker/**/*.ejs'
];
```

Comment: Server side views live in /views and client templates live in /assets/templates. I want to avoid having duplicate code, so wish to build the server side views from the client templates. This will allow me to enable pushState. To do this I need the views & templates to be in the same 'language' and use the same syntax, which they currently aren't. I seem to be having issues with both these points - referencing assets/templates from /views and getting a standard syntax

Answer (score 0):

[Consolidate.js](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js) does [support Underscore as an engine](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/Readme.md#L40) as of [version 0.3.1](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/commit/d70881c3d60c1fe6403ae22d162ec39fb96c7946), and Lodash as of [version 0.10.0](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/commit/ab15474c8e5d29b7f78d909297c1feca472e31fa).

Sails.js [supports all of the view engines compatible with Express via Consolidate](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views), but the first version of Sails to include Consolidate as a direct dependency is [only 0.12.0-rc2](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/d76048e0defb3f2548ad49acb5812d621e65d722/package.json). I'm not sure how Sails managed other template engines before this, but the [documentation suggests that Underscore has been supported as a view engine since 0.10.0](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.10-final/concepts/Views/ViewEngines.md).

You should verify that the version of Sails that you're using supports Underscore as a view engine, and make sure that you `npm i --save underscore` before you attempt to use it.